# One word for a reward that will not be given

Tags: single-word-requests, example, story

Is there any one word term to express something which is promised, but only to trick others to commit something, and will never be given.

Say, I promise my friend, "If you do it, I'll give 100 bucks". Later, when he comes to seek the reward, I just find an excuse and avoid him. Insurance claims may fall into this category too.

Additionally, can anyone think of a story (like a fable/gospel) that illustrates such a scenario?

Answer (score 1):

I think that *the carrot and stick metaphor* illustrates the point you want to make:

> The phrase "carrot and stick" is a metaphor for the use of a combination of reward and punishment to induce a desired behavior.
>
> Thus, the metaphor can serve as a visualization of what can sometimes happen in corporate and other settings, with executives "dangling" a promotion, for example (the "carrot") in front of the rank and file in order to get massive amounts of work out of them in exchange for very little reward.
>
> ***In general usage, any promised reward that is really a tease may be referred to as a "dangling carrot."***

(Wikipedia)